# Exercise 1.24 from The c programming language

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char brackets[20];
    int frequency[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        frequency[i] = 0;

    printf("the array: ");
    scanf("%s", brackets);



    for (char ch = '!'; ch <= '}';  ch++)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(brackets) &&  ok1; i++)
        {

            if (ch == brackets[i])
                frequency[ch-'0']++; // we keep increase the character position frequency.

        }


    }

    int ok = 1;
    int a[100], l=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    if (frequency[i] > 0)
    {

        printf("frec %d appears on %d\n", frequency[i], i);
        a[l] = frequency[i];
        l++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l-1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
        if (a[i] != a[i + 1])
            ok = 0;
    }
    if (ok)
        printf("yes");
    else 
        printf("no");

    _getch();

}
```

Hi guys,
I am learning C from The C Programming Language and I have to solve a problem that tells me the rudimentary syntax errors. I decided to use a frequency vector that keeps track of my parentheses s.a ( ) [ ]. The problem that I face is how i can figure it out if for example ) is before (. I tried using ASCII table, but it was not good. First point was to see if they appear in an equal number. Now I have to see if they  are placed correctly.
Thank you guys !!!

Comment: You should post the exercise as well.

Comment: What is `ok1`? You use it in the `for` loop, but never declare it or assign it.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you trying to figure out how to tell if brackets are properly balanced? So `({})` is good but `(}){` is bad?

Comment: You should create another array that you use as a stack. Whenever you see an opening bracket, you push it onto the stack. When you see a closing bracket, pop the top element off the stack and check if it's the correct opening for the current close bracket.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. I guarantee that K&R ("The C Programming Language") does *not* define `main` with a `void` return type. You've picked up that bad habit from somewhere else.

Comment: In addition to the stack suggested by Barmar, you should add a flag to indicate when you are within a string. In that case don't push any new characters on the stack,